# HTML 5 background video code seems to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I found a website called coverr.co that provides pre-made code for free html5 background videos. I can't seem to get the code to work even just by copying and pasting what they provided. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Could it be that my directories are all messed up? I've been messing around with this code for hours and I can't seem to get the video to work in the background.

```
<style type="text/css">

.homepage-hero-module {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
 }

.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
 display: none;
}

.no-video .video-conatiner .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster{
 display: block !important;
}

.video-container {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #000;
}

.video-container .poster img {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.video-container video {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}

.video-container video.fillWidth {
width: 100%;
}

   </style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    //jQuery is required to run this code
$( document ).ready(function() {

    scaleVideoContainer();

initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    scaleVideoContainer();
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
});

});

function scaleVideoContainer() {

var height = $(window).height() + 5;
var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
$('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){

$(element).each(function(){
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
});

scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
windowHeight = $(window).height() + 5,
videoWidth,
videoHeight;

console.log(windowHeight);

$(element).each(function(){
    var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width');

    $(this).width(windowWidth);

    if(windowWidth < 1000){
        videoHeight = windowHeight;
        videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
        $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});

        $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);
    }

    $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');

});
}

</script>




<body>

<div class="homepage-hero-module">
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="filter"></div>
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
        <source src="../MP4/BnW.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
        <source src="../WEBM/BnW.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
    <div class="poster hidden">
        <img src="../img/BnW.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your folder structure like? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: may be display:none in css create problem

Comment: @Roy I have my index.html file in my public_html folder and within that I have a folder called "mp4" where my mp4 video for the background is and webm file in a "webm" folder. In my HTML file, how should I link the files? ../mp4/BnW.mp4 is not working. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right. The directory structure might be messed up and the best way to ensure that is to check the browser's `Console` or `Network` tab in case of any error in fetching the resources.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/5ej6kxnv/) a jsFiddle script of your code working perfectly. Nothing really to add except that I've changed the `src` of the video and image tags to online media resources.

Comment: I have my index.html file in my public_html folder and within that I have a folder called "mp4" where my mp4 file for the background is and webm file in a "webm" folder. In my HTML file, how should I link the files? ../mp4/BnW.mp4 is not working. Is that correct?

Comment: If the `index.html` is in the `public_html` folder as well as the `mp4` folder, you can use dot-slash `./` where you identify the `current working directory` rather than going up one level by using double-dot-slash `../`.